# The best length of data sent by TCP/IP protocol

Tags: sockets

I'm fresh about socket programming under UNIX. Now I'm confusing about the best length of

buffer.For example, If I want to send 15M's data to others, how can I do it? How big should

I define the buffer?

Comment: I would match it with the underlying HW buffer size. I believe it is of the order of the typical Ethernet IP packet length. No more than 8 kilos, I think.

Comment: @Val: I don't think it would make any difference, it's up to the OS to care about such details. If you passed one big buffer to `write`, it should take care by itself to provide it to the HW buffer in the best-sized chunks, and by using a bigger buffer you'll avoid the overhead of repeatedly going into kernel mode (although such overhead is normally negligible for network stuff).

Comment: @MatteoItalia if its small than the maximum packet payload size, it can impact performance, as depending on the time it takes to write the new data, the OS can send the packet smaller.

Comment: @DiegoCNascimento: of course, my comment was against being overly clever about the exact size; just pass a biggish buffer (many times the usual packets sizes, but small enough to avoid wasting too much memory) and be happy with it. Even better, if the data send has to be blocking and you already have all the data in a big buffer, just pass such buffer.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen JETTY for example buffering on 8KB basis in their implementation of `ServletInputStream` and `ServletOutputStream`. So your buffer should be a multiple of this.

This is, what we can recommend on the socket side. The actual buffer size you use, should as large as possible to minimize overhead between sending two buffers and should be as small as possible to keep the footprint of your process small.

If you want to send 15MB and 15MB is not much for your hardware, well create a 15MB Buffer.

Comment: _So your buffer should be a multiple of this_. A multiple of 8KB, why!? It can be a multiple of packet payload size, or depending on performance, it can be based on system call data transfer, paging, etc

Answer (score 0):

The buffer size will be much dependent on your application. And I'm assuming this buffer is just to pass the data to the OS.

So like said, if you pass a bigger buffer than a packet payload can get, it can be divided into multiple packets, avoiding more than necessary system calls and data transfer between application and OS.

On the other side a bigger than necessary buffer would consume system memory without needing too, and depending on the OS, driver, and the exaggerated buffer size you can have problems with the system call.

So it will vary depending on the application and system. Maybe you can put it is as a configuration or not.